# PnP Powershell Sharepoint with app permissions: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Tags: powershell, authentication, sharepoint-online

I'd like to use PnP Powershell for provisioning modern Sharepoint Online sites by making a copy of an existing site in the tenant.  I'm running the SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline module, version 3.22.2006.2.

If I connect using the `-UseWebLogin` option like this:

`Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<sitename> -UseWebLogin`

…and then run

`Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Out file.xml`

…then everything works fine, and I can then go on to provision a new site from the XML file that it creates.

What I'd **like** to do, however, is to use Application Permissions with a Registered App in Azure AD.  I've registered an app, and given it every Sharepoint-related permission I can think of (with a view to cutting permissions back to the minimum once I've got it working).  I connect like this:

`connect-PnPOnline -ClientID "<ClientID>" -ClientSecret "<ClientSecret>" -url https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<sitename>`

... and it appears to make the connection with no issues.  However, when I try to run the following:

`Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Out file.xml`

…it fails with the error:

```
Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Provisioning.Site.GetProvisioningTemplate
```

The permissions I gave my Azure AD Registered App are:

- Microsoft Graph: Directory.ReadWrite.All
- Microsoft Graph: Group.Create
- Microsoft Graph:  Group.ReadWrite.All
- Microsoft Graph: Sites.FullControl.All
- Microsoft Graph: Sites.Manage.All
- Microsoft Graph: Sites.Read.All
- Microsoft Graph: Sites.ReadWrite.All
- Sharepoint: Sites.FullControl.All
- Sharepoint: Sites.Manage.All
- Sharepoint: Sites.Read.All
- Sharepoint: TermStore.Read.All
- Sharepoint: TermStore.ReadWrite.All
- Sharepoint: User.Read.All
- Sharepoint: User.ReadWrite.All

I also tried creating a Sharepoint App Principal according to this article: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/03/connect-pnponline-with-appid-and-appsecret.html.  If I use the Client ID and Client Secret from this in my `connect-PnpOnline` line, again I can connect with no issues.  But again I get the same error when trying to run `Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate`.

I've also tried connecting to a different site within the same tenant, and I get the same error with all of them.

I'm starting to run out of ideas on this - can anyone shed some light, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working.

When I created my Sharepoint App Principal, I'd granted it permissions with this XML:

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
       <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

But what I *needed* was:

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
       <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

...in other works FullControl for the whole tenant, not just SiteCollection.

Comment: The main point is that PnPProvisioningTemplate engine does rely on SharePoint Online Service and not Graph based connection. Using SPO principal or AzureAd with Certificate allows you access via SPO Services.

Answer (score 0):

You can also register the app on Azure AD. if in that case, you need to configure a Certificate and grant permission to SharePoint API instead of MS Graph.

[image]

Below is the tutorial:

- [Setting up an Azure AD app for app-only access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread#setting-up-an-azure-ad-app-for-app-only-access)

BR

Comment: Thanks Baker - that's what I ended up doing.  The Sharepoint app-only approach seemed a bit old-school. If only I'd seen the FAQ at the bottom of the page you linked to.  Q: Can I use other means besides certificates for realizing app-only access for my Azure AD app?  A: No, all other options are blocked by SharePoint Online and will result in an Access Denied message.